# Shuffle DefaultListModel

Tags: java, swing, collections, jlist, defaultlistmodel

Is there a quickest way to shuffle the items of a `DefaultListModel` other than copying all elements in a separate `arraylist`, I'm using the code below, but it gives me a `java.lang.ClassCastException` :

```
....
private DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<String>();
...
Collections.shuffle((List<?>) listModel, new java.util.Random(seed));
...
```

Any suggestion

Comment: How do you get the items into the `DefaultListModel` in the first place?

Comment: addElement() function

Comment: So presumably you have a loop for adding elements into the list model??

Comment: Okay. So instead of adding the elements to the list model, add them to a `List` instead, shuffle the list then use the `toArray` method to construct the `ListModel`

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Not completely sure of the indices but</strike> something like this:

```java
private DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<String>();
...
static void shuffle(DefaultListModel<String> mdl){
    for(int i=0;i<mdl.size();i++){
        int swapWith = (int)(Math.random()*(mdl.size()-i))+i;
        if(swapWith==i) continue;
        mdl.add(i, mdl.remove(swapWith));
        mdl.add(swapWith, mdl.remove(i+1));
    }
}
```